# What is the reason for UnsupportedClassVersionError?

Tags: java

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:676)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:317)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:280)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.MacLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
at apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.run(LaunchRunner.java:115)
at apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.callMain(LaunchRunner.java:50)
at apple.launcher.JavaApplicationLauncher.launch(JavaApplicationLauncher.java:52)
```

I don't understand this at all; can anyone explain it simply? Thanks

Comment: Retagged from javascript to java.

Comment: @Rob, you could have fixed the code formatting, title, and remove txtisms while you were there. :)

Comment: It means something broke.  Perhaps with more code of what you're trying to do someone could explain what happened.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java error: Bad version number in .class file error when trying to run Cassandra on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611312/java-error-bad-version-number-in-class-file-error-when-trying-to-run-cassandra)

Comment: How are you compiling and running? See also [`UnsupportedClassVersionError `](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError.html).

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/07/javalangunsupportedclassversionerror.html is nice post on the issue.

Answer (score 12):

This error can occur when you compile the code with a newer version of the JDK and try to run it on an older version of the [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine). Is this your own code you're compiling and are you using an IDE (like Eclipse)? Try updating your [JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: use java -version and javac -version to compare the version of your compiler vs the version of the JVM.

Comment: @Kevin This is actually a mistake that many beginners make when they start learning Java. Since we all were there once we should be tolerant of the mistakes that are made by the beginners.

Comment: How would i go about updating my JRE?

Comment: I don't use mac so I can't help you. But you might want to go to superuser.com or apple.stackexchange.com and ask there how to upgrade your JVM.

Comment: @Peter - Do what Vincent suggested and type in `java -version` in your command prompt (assuming that your Java environment variables are installed). It'll tell you what version you have. You can download the latest version in the link in my answer.

Comment: This is what happened in the commnand prompt


java version "1.5.0_28"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_28-b04-382-9M3326)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_28-157, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Current version is 1.6 so it's quite possible that your code has been compiled with 1.6 instead of 1.5 (your current JRE version). You can either target 1.5 with your code, or you can download the latest JRE from the link in my answer.

Comment: For just the `JRE`, go here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre-6u25-download-346243.html and select your operating system.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed you using Mac. I'm not familiar with Macs. Google comes up with various results, or you go directly to Apple's site. This post might help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577014/how-install-a-specific-jdk-on-mac-os-x

Comment: i updated to 1.6.2.04 or whatever and it still doesnt work any other ideas?

Comment: What version do you get when you type `javac -version` (notice the `c` at the end of java)

Comment: Java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07-334-9M3326)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02-334, mixed mode)

Comment: I'm not familiar with macs, so maybe someone else has experience with Mac and Java. What you could try is targetting your code to compile to a different version number. How you do this depends on what IDE you're using.

Comment: whats an IDE and how would i go about finding which one im using??

Comment: IDE is an Integrated Development Environment. `Eclipse` is an example of an IDE (google it). How did you compile the code? Did you use something like `Eclipse` or straight command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

It means that your compiler was producing something targeted at a higher Java version than the JVM you are attempting to run it on.

eg compiled for java 6 and running with java 5.

Solution 1: upgrade the jvm (type java -version to see what you have)

Solution 2: target a lower version (in eclipse java compiler settings, for example)

Answer (score 1):

JAVA_HOME should be defined with the java version that younger ot the same that you used for compilation.

Answer (score 0):

It is saying you are using class file for different version of java runtime. What program are you installing (I notice installj in your stacktrace)?

Try upgrading your Java runtime.

Comment: Im trying to install a program called marvin sketch for my orgo lab, i thought i had to change my java so i did but now i dont know how to fix it

Comment: What did you mean by changing your java? Did you do something to your java prior to running the installation program?

Comment: Yea, i went here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

and download one of the programs but i dont know which one im so confused:(

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I installed `JRE` 1.8 and tried to run `Hello World` of `GAE application` on `Eclipse Kepler`. This is solution:

I installed `Java 8 support for Kepler` from `Eclipse Marketplace`. Then I resolved my problem by going to `Eclipse` -> Right click on project file -> `Properties` -> `Java Build Path`, I removed `JRE System Library 1.6`, clicked `Add Library` -> `JRE System Library` -> `Installed JRE's`. Then I clicked `Search`, it automatically found version `1.8` and then I returned to previous view, selected 1.8 and now everything works fine!