# Which JRE version to use while making new Java Project in Eclipse and what are the drawbacks?

Tags: eclipse, java, java-7

In Eclipse when i create new Java Project, i see options like:

[image]

Now i want to know, what is the safest option to use considering when i export jar file any user will be able to use it. If selecting the shown option, does that mean if someone has JRE 1.6, he will not be able to run that jar file, or is it backward compatible??

As such my project has no specific 1.7 dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very broad question, which JRE to use depends on your requirement. If you have multiple projects, each specific to a JRE, then you can use project specific JRE. If you are happy with eclipse default JRE you can continue. It is purely your decision.

Someone with JRE 1.6 should be able to run on 1.6 as long as compilation level is set to 1.6 (This may flag if your code has any 1.7 features which are not part of 1.6).

Comment: thanks, just i want to know is there any mechanism that we can explicitly lock the user to have certain JRE else the project should fail, by setting any option here or these options are irrelevant and it all depends on my code which functionality it uses.

Comment: It is mixed, if you set compliance level to certain jdk, that will force your user to use same level of JRE/JDK, otherwise it will throw UnsupportedClassVersionError. When you are compiling your code certain jdk means, you are code ultimately follows that version of JDK API. This SO link has example case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611312/java-error-bad-version-number-in-class-file-error-when-trying-to-run-cassandra

Comment: This is very interesting thing to know. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

If you use features which are specific to JDK 7 (such as the new NIO.2/The path API ) then they most likely won't work on java 6. Furthermore Java 6 has been tested and withstood the test of time as a result most (if not all) bugs have been ironed out. Java 7 is still fairly new and even after it was released there was a pesky bug that showed up couple of days after release which had to the with the loop optimisation. So unless you specifically need JDK7 features I'd suggest you stick with JDK6, on the other hand if your project is not mission-critical then you might experiment with the new JDK7 features given that your user base has JRE 7. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: thanks but if i use JDK6 and the target user is running JDK7, that means it would still work right? Im just asking because then do i need to explicity set JDK version in Eclipse while making a new project, or just use the default? So a safe practice would be to use the lowest possible version that works with your project?

Comment: @Johnydep: Yes (well, almost always ;-) ). Java is firmly committed to provide downwards compatibility, so old code should run on a newer JRE. There have been a few problems in that area, but they are fairly rare. In general, if you develop with some version of the JDK, it will run on this and any later version.

Comment: I like this answer because it gives me the sense that JDK7 is the Python3 of Java.