# Need some pointers with this Java starter program

Tags: java, debugging, javac, unsupported-class-version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java error: Bad version number in .class file error when trying to run Cassandra on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611312/java-error-bad-version-number-in-class-file-error-when-trying-to-run-cassandra)

I am not sure i am doing anything wrong with this *basic* hello world program. Have no idea why does this throw errors.

I have saved the file as `test.java`.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }

    /*public static void sop(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }*/
}
```

When i compile it with `javac test.java`, it compiles successfully, but when i try to run it by using `java test`, it gives the following error:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop>java test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
```

The Java `bin` directory is added in System path. Would appreciate any pointers.

Java directories in the system path are as follows:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib;`

The java/javac versions:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop>java -version
java version "1.5.0_12"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_12-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_12-b04, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Users\admin\Desktop>javac -version
javac 1.6.0_31
```

Thanks.

Comment: you are trying to run class in java lower version which is compiled in higher version.

Comment: First test on your side: call both `java -version` and `javac -version`. I guess, that the version of `java` has a lower version number then `javac`. You may have an older JRE sitting on your PATH before the JDK.

Comment: That exception is telling you that the Java VM being used to run the code is older than the compiler that was used to generate the bytecode.

Did you perhaps use an IDE to compile the `.java` into the `.class` file?

Or did you invoke a newer `javac`?

Comment: Please check whether both javac -version and java -version show the same number.

Comment: @Andreas-d - I've included my java/javac version numbers and system path vars. Please let me know if this is the issue. Am a beginner in Java. :)

Comment: @Pushpesh - the java/javac versions you posted indicate you are compiling under java 6 yet running under java 5. please fux your env/path so that java and javac come from the same place (or at least are the same version). failing that, specify 1.5 as the target version when compiling your code

Comment: @radai Thanks a lot for the info. Will try to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your java compiler is version 1.6.0 and your java executable environment is version 1.5.0.

The error is to tell you that your java executable to too new for the java executable environment.

To solve your problem you need to update your java environment (or downgrade your java compiler).

Comment: *"you need to update your java environment (or downgrade your java compiler)..."* Or use the cross-compilation options of `javac` - which would be the best way to do it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks a lot to both of you. I will do the necessary JDK updates.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes, that would indeed a better solution :D

Comment: i believe the main problem is the PATH variable of your system - there must be on older version of java.exe listed BEFORE the newer JDK. Maybe the java.exe found in the system32 directory under the WINDOWS directory

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that your test class is improperly titled.

Class names should be capitalized according the ANSI standard.

Comment: It has nothing to do with that. All that Java requires is that `the class name and file name should match.`